# How to format content in multicolumn list in latex

Tags: lists, itemize, multicol

I have tried finding the answer on google but to no avail, hence here.

I have a multicolumn list in my latex file.

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{itemize}
\item blah1
\item blah2 blah3 blah4
\item blah5 blah6

\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

So right now it automatically formats my multicolumn as -

blah1 and blah2 in column1, blah3 and blah4 in column2 and remaining in column3.

however I want each item to be in its own column, so blah1 goes into column1, "blah2 blah3 blah4" goes into column2, and "blah5 blah6" go in column3.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Wouldn't this be simpler in a table? Alternatively, you could add `\columnbreak` at the end of each item.

Comment: I dont think so. Say I want to say "I am Tofu King" in column 1, "I am here for help" in column 2 and "This is my first question" in column 3. so whenever I would need to give a line break, I would have to break each of the itemized sentences apart and then "&" them to appear in next line.

Comment: So try the `\columnbreak` solution then.

Comment: This takes away the luxury of constantly being able to change the sentences when in need.

Comment: aah, columnbreak worked. Thanks! I am new to it..so..thanks again!

Comment: If you consider Alan's answer solved your problem, please consider marking his answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that works by appending `\columnbreak` to each item.  Note that this will not work if you have more items than columns, since subsequent column breaks will produce page breaks, which is not what you want.  Rather than add `\columnbreak` manually to each item, I've wrapped it in a command and then used `enumitem` to redefine the `\item` command locally within the list.  Since three column text produces quite nasty looking text when fully justified, I've added `\RaggedRight` (from the `ragged2e` package) which will do a nicer job of formatting the narrow columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% define a new command identical to \item
\let\colitem\item
% append \columnbreak to the new item command
\apptocmd{\colitem}{\columnbreak}{}{}
\begin{document}
% If you don't use the multicols* environment and have more items than columns
% you will get an error.  
\begin{multicols*}{3}
% Now using enumitem's "before" key, we make the list RaggedRight and redefine
% \item locally to mean \colitem
\begin{itemize}[before={\RaggedRight\let\item\colitem}]
\item This is the first item.
\item This is a longer sentence to see how it wraps.
\item This is the third item.
%\item With this scheme you can't have more items than columns (uncomment to see)
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]